# Snowpack Typescript Imports

Tags: typescript, snowpack

I'm running Snowpack and I have a Typescript package (hosted on Github packages) that I want to pull in via

```
import SomeClass from '@myRepo/lib'
```

however I'm getting the error

```
"/_snowpack/pkg/@myRepo.SomeClass.ts" is not a constructor
```

When I copy-paste the class to a local file and import it using local imports (like below), it works.

```
import SomeClass from './lib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was more to do with my understanding (or lack thereof) on Typescript development.

There were two things: First, I was incorrectly referencing a Typescript file in the `main` value of my `package.json`. Second, I hadn't correctly configured the build of my lib with appropriate `.d.ts` files.

My `package.json` ended up needing to look like this

```
...    
main: "dist/SomeClass.js",
types: "dist/SomeClass.d.ts",
...
```